# Many-to-Many association with one model and API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a relationship where a User can track multiple TVShows, and TVShow can have multiple Users tracking them.

The twist is TVShow is not a real model in the database, an API call is being made to themoviedb whenever a TVShow is searched or a page is requested.

I've seen Rails suggests self-joins when using only one model but I can't seem to make it work in this situation.

Comment: Hi - you'll need to show us the code you've tried and expand a bit more on "not working" - what do you observe? did you get an error? tell us more... (note: don't reply in the comments - edit your question and add the info there as this info should be a part of your question)